# Multiple dropdownlists with different bound values getting overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an app with 3 dropdownlists that are all declared with razor synatx and use the same source list but with different bound values. All three are nullable values:

```
[Required]
public int? PMDID1 { get; set; }
public int? PMDID2 { get; set; }
public int? PMDID3 { get; set; }
```

I get the list for the dropdownlist and save it to a session object and I've tried referencing the session object in the view itself, but right now I'm grabbing the value and adding it to the viewmodel so it's tightly bound.

```
var dlist = (List<SelectListItem>)Session["PDList"];
eavm.DList = new List<SelectListItem>(dlist);
return View(eavm);
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Encounter.PMDID1, Model.DList, "", new { @class = "pvb-fieldBox" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Encounter.PMDID2, Model.DList, "", new { @class = "pvb-fieldBox" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Encounter.PMDID3, Model.DList, "", new { @class = "pvb-fieldBox" })
```

What's happening is when I load this page with a previous entry, where PMDID1 has a value, but 2 and 3 are null, it's populating all 3 dropdownlists with the selected value of PMDID1 despite the fact that the others are bound to 2/3. What can I do to ensure if they are null they just display the "" empty start value?

Comment: Cannot duplicate this. If the value of `PMDID1` is set and matches an option value, the correct option will be selected, and if `PMDID2` and `PMDID3` are `null`, the first `""` option will be selected. (and I assume `eavm.DList` is a typo and its really `eavm.DiagnosisList` which is the property used in your view)

Comment: Sorry, fixed the list name in the question. But in code they do match. I handled it by checking if the property has a value and if not then I'm setting it to zero so the selected value is forced. That solution is meant to be a band-aid though.